# A bi-directional hashing algorithm?

Tags: hash

Is there an algorithm that will yield the same hash for two numbers, no matter what order they are in?

For example, hashing `3268` and `2642` should yield the same result as hashing `2642` and `3268`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "hashing two numbers?" Hash functions typically have a single input, not two.

Comment: Having two inputs doesn't make a hash function any less of a hash function, all it needs is a stable, single output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, XOR does that.

```
 3268^2642 == 2642^3268
```

There's a lot more (addition, multiplication, basically any commutative operation), but XOR is usually used for hashing anyway (because it's easy to "unhash").

Answer (score 4):

Hash the two numbers separately (using an integer-to-integer hash of your choice), and then either add or xor the results.

Answer (score 2):

You could add or XOR the two numbers before hashing them.

Comment: But adding before hashing means that there are inputs related in simple ways that give the same hash -- such as (12345,88273) and (12346,88272). You get more symmetry than was asked for, and too much symmetry is a bad thing in a hash.